# loading XML only if given attribute does not exist at least once, or contains a given value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

assume I would have an xml and I'd like to validate this file using .net (C#) to verify if as follows :

- If at least one of the file nodes has no filter, do something
- If all the files have a filter attribute, and at least one of this
  matches a filter value do something
- if neither of above are met, do nothing

I've been struggling harder as expected, and came up with hugely complex code, and I'm sure this can be done simpler as what I tried.

Some examples : accepted filter value would be 'nl'

```
<!-- some nodes above -->
<file name="something"/>
<file name="something else"/>
<file name="and something else" filter="en, fr, de"/>
<!-- more nodes below -->
```

This passes as there is at least one file without filter value

```
<!-- some nodes above -->
<file name="something" filter="nl, hu"/>
<file name="something else" filter="ru"/>
<file name="and something else" filter="en, fr, de"/>
<!-- more nodes below -->
```

This would also pass as at least one file matches the 'nl' restriction (the first file)

```
<!-- some nodes above -->
<file name="something" filter="pt, hu"/>
<file name="something else" filter="ru"/>
<file name="and something else" filter="en, fr, de"/>
<!-- more nodes below -->
```

This one should fail as neither one of the files lack the filter attribute, and neither one of the filters contains 'nl'

Any advice on what would be the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Unless you have a boat-load (that is, many thousands) of nodes to check, I'm a big fan of using `XmlSerializer` to simply read in your full XML data into an in-memory data object model. Then you can use any built-in C# code/logic to filter the data. Unless you have specific performance issues doing this, I find it the simplest and most maintainable. (Bonus: you can use this same logic to verify your file filters if you have users editing them in your program) EDIT: Bonus2: it separates your serialization concerns making it easy add/change filters, or better to track/report or unit test issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried linq2xml?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"data.xml");

var restrict = "nl";
var anyMissingFilter = (from filter in doc.Descendants("file")
                         where filter.Attribute("filter") == null
                         select 1).Any();
var anyRestrictionMatch = (from filter in doc.Descendants("file")
                           where 
                               filter.Attribute("filter") != null &&
                               filter.Attribute("filter").Value.Contains(restrict)
                           select 1).Any();
```

Comment: I haven't really looked at this. I'm actually refreshing my knowledge as I got stuck a few years in time and am still converting my .net 1 VB skills to the latest C#, ca be a bit of a challenge sometimes... This looks promising at least, I assume I just need to do a check that if either anyMissingFilter or anyRestrictionMatch contains content I'm safe to go ?

Comment: They're both bool; the Any() method simply returns true if/when it reaches the first matching condition.

Comment: Great, I actually managed to put it in one block as follows 
var validNodes = (from files in doc.Descendants("file")
where  files.Attribute("locales") == null || files.Attribute("locales").Value.Contains(locale) select 1).Any();
if (validNodes== true) { rest of code } 
works like a charm, thanks !

Comment: To Georg's point, if you have a large document or need every bit if performance you can get, you'll want a streaming approach. This method will create a document out of the entire XML tree.

Comment: Fair enough. The files are rather small (approx 100k) so this method should work fine. I'll dive into streaming also, but this one get's me already out of trouble for now

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass through the Xml file with the method of your choice (XmlReader, Linq to Xml, XmlDocument). If you find a file that either contains no filter or a filter that matches your criterion, the file validates. Otherwise it does not.

The most efficient way would certainly to use a plain XmlReader, because this way you don't save the hole Xml in memory. The other methods also use XmlReader internally, but are more convenient.